# Overwrite existing alarm

Tags: android, android-alarms

I create an alaram in my app which is calling a BroadcastReceiver to setup notifications ever day with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Benachrichtigung.CUSTOM_INTENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

alram = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alram.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Now I want that the user can set the time for the norification so I have to call `calendar.set` with the new value. How can I overwrite the existing alarm with a new one?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Is it not overwriting it now?

Comment: If I call exactly this code with an other hour for example `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9)` does it overwrite the old alarm automatically? So is the old alarm with 8 deleted and the new with 9 created automatically?

Comment: Have you tested it yet to see what happens?

Comment: No because I don't know how I should test it. Can I view anywhere which alarms are set in the system?

Comment: Well, what I would suggest is using a time that will trigger in a couple of minutes then another that would trigger a couple minutes after that and see if it works as expected. I know giving you the answer would be easier but not as helpful :)

Comment: Okay I tested it and come to the result that it overwrites the old alarm automaticlly. Is that the result that you have expected?

Comment: Its what I expected but more importantly is it what YOU expected?

Comment: I thought that maybe two different alarms are created because I call the same function two times. Of cause I can create two different alarms with different intents in my app. Is the same intent in this example the reason for the system to overwrite an existing alarm?

Comment: Yes. I have posted an answer that hopefully explains it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To cancel or update an alarm using `AlarmManager` the `Intent` must match using the filterEquals. So basically, you re-create the `PendingIntent` the same as you did for the original and `AlarmManager` will see that they are the same. This includes the `REQUEST_CODE`,  `INTENT_ACTION`, and `INTENT_DATA` (I may be missing something there but those are important.

**Note:**

`EXTRAS` are not used in comparing the two `Intent`s.

So if the two `Intent`s are equal then the first will be overwritten. When I have more time I can try and find a resource to better explain that.

According to the [Intent Docs filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent))

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

Comment: Great answer thanks for your help! The way that I tested it with you was great to learn a bit more about android! Thanks for that.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help. I try to pass on what I have learned from great SO members such as Sam, prosperk, pragnani, commonsware, and others. Which is Explaining why/how things work is often much more helpful than simply providing code :)

Comment: Just to be clear, `Context` doesn't matter? I have different parts of my app in different classes calling my AlarmUtil static function of setAlarm, and I'm worried that I might be just creating multiple alarms. Nor the alarm duration?

Comment: @the_gesslar correct, the context won't cause it to cause it to create a new alarm. I do just that because I need to canccel, delete, update alarms in different classes, as well.