# Intent extras don't seem to refresh

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

When I press the button it calls a method which gets user input and sets it to a variable, then that variable is put to an intent extra and sent to BroadcastReceiver which decides what to do depending on that value. It only works the first time, on all the next presses intent extra value isn't changed no matter if that variable value changes. It forever holds the value which is set at the first press. How to rewrite intent extra with a new value?

How I set the extra:

```
Intent intentForReceiver = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intentForReceiver.putExtra("checkBox1", checkBox1.isChecked());
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
intentForReceiver, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

How I receive the extra on BroadcastReceiver and put it to the intent for service:

```
Intent intentForService = new Intent(context, CMService.class);
intent.putExtra("checkBox1", intentForReceiver.getExtras().getBoolean("checkBox1"));
context.startService(intentForService);
```

How I receive the extra on Service:

```
if(intentForService.getExtras().getBoolean("checkBox1")) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

So this is my code. If I uncheck the checkBox1 and press the button, it still does the job which should be done only if checkBox1.isChecked() is true, so it means this value stays true forever after the first press and doesn't update when I uncheck the checkBox1.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working

Comment: I'm away from my pc now. But it's very easy code. I just create an intent, set the extra and pass it to pending intent which is used by alarmmanager and starts broadcastreceiver. All I need is to rewrite the old intent extra with the new value. Maybe clear intent extras before setting it again should help but how to do it?

Comment: When you get back to your PC, post the relevant code

Comment: I edited my question with some code. Please check it

Comment: You need to cancel the old alarm and set a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before recreating your alarm, cancel the first one. To do this, you recreate your `Intent` and call cancel on the `AlarmManager`. For instance, I have a method in an `Alarm` class that cancels it for me before starting a new one

```
// cancel existing logout alarm
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
     REQUEST_CODE, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);     
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Then recreate the `PendingIntent` and set the new `AlarmManager`

[This answer explains a little more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200069/overwrite-existing-alarm/17201010#17201010)