# Android Overwriting current Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm trying to set an alarm notification once, and each time a User logs in, overwrite or cancel the previous alarm and set a new one. Based primarily on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867051/intent-extras-dont-seem-to-refresh?lq=1) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200069/overwrite-existing-alarm/17201010#17201010) a tried the following code:

```
private void cancelPreviousAlarm(){
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            REQUEST_CODE, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
}

public void setAlarmBirthday (String message, String fechaNacimiento, boolean notified, boolean isLogin){

    Long time2 = calculateNextBirthday(fechaNacimiento, notified, isLogin);
    Long alertTime2 = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+time2;

    AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alertIntentBirthday = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);

    cancelPreviousAlarm();

    alertIntentBirthday.putExtra(EXTRA_BIRTHDAY_MESSAGE, message);
    alertIntentBirthday.putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_LOCAL_NOTI, true);

    alarmManager3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime2, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE,
            alertIntentBirthday, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));

}
```

But only sets the first alarm and not the next ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` with  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

**FLAG_ONE_SHOT:**

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once.
>         For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
>         {@link #getService}.
>
> If set, after
>         {@link #send()} is called on it, it will be automatically
>         canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

**FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT**:

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, 
>   then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
>   Intent. For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and 
>   {@link #getService}.
>
> This can be used if you are creating intents
>   where only the   extras change, and don't care that any entities that
>   received your   previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with
>   your new   extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had flags on '0' and they were always the same data, I changed them to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and now the data is overwritten